# Assessing Haskell speed

Tags: c, performance, haskell

In short: I need to check Haskell speed on simple operations, and currently have poor results, but I'm not sure if I doing compilation/optimization right.

*UPD: The problem is **answered**, see comments - the trouble was in different integer type...*

In details:

I work in a project where a number of services are doing bulk-processing on data, so that at least certain part of these services simply need to be fast. They are doing some heavy calculations and manipulations on data, not only extract-load. In other words it is a matter of how many instances and hours are going to be spent on say on each `1e15` records of data.

Currently we are considering adding a few more services to project and some of colleagues are curious to try writing them in different language from those already used. I'm less or more ok with it, but I insist we check the "core performance" of the proposed languages first. Surely speed testing is hard and controversial, so I propose we use very simple test, with simple operations and without complex data structures etc. We agreed for "poor recursive" fibonacci function:

```
fib x
  | x < 2 = x
  | otherwise = fib (x - 2) + fib (x - 1)

main = print (fib 43)
```

I wrote it in several languages for comparison. The C version looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib(int x) {
    return (x < 2) ? x : (fib(x - 2) + fib (x - 1));
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", fib(43));
}
```

I compile the first with `ghc -O2 test.hs` and the latter with `gcc -O2 test.c`. GHC version is 8.4.3. Right now I see results differing about 12 times (2.2 seconds on C version, 3 seconds on Java version and 30 seconds on Haskell in the same machine).

**I wonder if I did everything about compiler and compiler options right. For I thought as Haskell compiles to native-code (?) it should be comparable to C and similar languages. And I need hints on this.**

*P.S. Please, don't say that fibonacci function could be written without "exponential" recursion - I know - but as I said we need some test with a lot of simple calculations.*

*P.P.S. I don't mean if we can't make Haskell faster we won't use it. But probably we'll reserve it for some other service where time is spent mainly on input-output, so it won't matter. For current bunch of "speed-critical" services it's just the matter of whether the customer will pay $10000 or $120000 for these instances monthly.*

Comment: This is a consequence of using a *wrong* algorithm: this `fib` will scale *exponentially*. Furthermore part of the problem is the laziness of the parameters. By writing `fib !x` in the head, instead of `fib x`, this should probably result in an efficiencyboost.

Comment: The problem here is that without the exact algorithms the benchmarking might be useless. So just calculating simple things might be fine and doing something what’s actually wanted might suddenly be very slow, or very fast, compared to that. If you’re not doing this kind of exponential calculation then the benchmark won’t show much.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I hope you have seen the first "P.S." - or you mean something different. How "wrong algorithm" can affect performance in one language but not the other?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen - you are right, but we anyway need some considerations to be approved by customer's technicians. It would be very painful to quarrel half a year later about "why have you chose the technology knowing it will hurt our finances" etc... We need to have some agreement with them on how and what we choose, you see...

Comment: @RodionGorkovenko: well see it like this, languages are optimized towards a certain "code style". For example C, etc. definitely aim to optimize the "process" of a function call. In Python for example function calls are very expensive, but the "scope" of Python is different: providing a convenient way to make function calls, and a nice interface to certain libraries that thus can perform operations in bulk (ex. with numpy). Haskell on the other hand has laziness, and thus works good if you for example generate a list, and later never want to read more than 10 elements of it.

Comment: What I mean is that there is a "Haskell-ish" style as well as a "Pythonic" solution. In (online) programming contests, I've managed to implement algorithms that usually ended (in terms of runtime) in the top 10% (sometimes no noticable difference versus the "fastest" C++ equivalent), Not because the algorithm was faster, but because you can use the "language tools" in a better way.

Comment: For example one thing that might here have impact is setting the type of `fib` to `fib :: Int -> Int`. Right now it is any `Num` type. If it uses `Integer`, then this will easily get slow, because you now use arbitrary sized integers, not fixed-length integers.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for hint, I'll check it soon!

Comment: Did you compare the results of these two algorithms, and notice that the C version is wrong for large input, but the Haskell version is correct?  That might give you a hint.

Comment: Adding `fib :: Int -> Int` here improves the performance to 2.2x slower than C.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I've just tested your suggestion. Really that was the root of the problem. So if you make your comment to proper answer, I will readily mark it as accepted. The running time is reduced to 3 seconds. I'm happy that I spent efforts asking question here instead of angrily dismissing Haskell as an option :)

Comment: Plus a non tail recursive function is maybe not the best thing to do with Haskell to compare it to other language.

Comment: Please, consider that developing in a new language (where everybody of your team is an entry level programmer though an enthusiastic) will definitely push your costs to an indefinite but significant amount. How many run-time microseconds do you need to safe for the customer to amortize this? IMHO, developers are often enthusiastic with new toys but don't consider the economical effects too much... ;-) (I must admit that I'm developer myself.)

Comment: @Scheff developers are always enthusiastic :) and we know that using unknown or rare language increases costs. However currently large parts of solution are written in Erlang and proceeding in this way will increase costs too much (with given amounts of data) compared to switching to Java, Scala, Haskell or anything similar (as Erlang is executed from specific byte-code and not specially optimized for great performance... it has slightly different goals)...

Comment: This is what I found just recently (accidentally): [The Rest Of The Story](https://codahale.com/the-rest-of-the-story/). I was reminded to it as you mentioned Scala. May be, having read this motivated me to write my above comment although that reflects my own opinion. (I must admit I'm not sure if it is in any way helpful to solve your problem/dilemma...)

Comment: May be, a more helpful hint: For a decision concerning future usage of a language, you may also consider the quantity of available docs, code base, and problem solutions in the internet. (IMHO, this point goes to C/C++.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff this is more and more off-topic, but yes, this is a very important point. Though for most of these languages things are less or more similar. Another point is the amount of libraries (and library repos!) and tools (as enterprise solutions usually are not written from scratch).